# React native: maintaining state of child components in Segment view

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

I am using React Native + Native base to have a segment view. Each button fo the segment renders a different view below (child component). However when I switch between the views by switching the state the segment is via a button press, and then switch back I can see that the child component is re-rendered as it doesnt maintain the scroll position of my list. My question is, is there a way to not unmount the child components and in a way maintain state within the views (child components) when I switch back and forth between segment state?

in the code below the Calendar component would be the child component. And changing the state of the segment would flip between displaying and not displaying the Calendar.

```
<Container style={styles.testContainer}>


       <Segment style={{backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
              <Button
              style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.seg === 1 ? "white" : undefined,
              borderColor: "white"}}
               first
               active={this.state.seg === 1 ? true : false}
                                onPress={() => this.setState({ seg: 1 })}
                >
                <Text style={{ color: this.state.seg === 1 ? "#2c6da4" : "white" }}>Posts</Text></Button>
              <Button last last
                                style={{
                                    backgroundColor: this.state.seg === 2 ? "white" : undefined,
                                    borderColor: "white",
                                }}
                                active={this.state.seg === 2 ? true : false}
                                onPress={() => this.setState({ seg: 2 })}
                            ><Text style={{ color: this.state.seg === 2 ? "blue" : "white" }}>Profile</Text></Button>
            </Segment>

        {this.state.seg === 1 ? <Calendar onSelectDate={this.onSelectDate} /> : null }

      </Container>
```

Comment: use [shouldComponentUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) to prevent unwanted rerendering